# Ubuntu server 14.04 crashing after while

Tags: server

My ubuntu server 14.04 stops working after week or so. If I reboot it, it starts working again and works for a while but in a week it stops responding to pings and I cannot ssh or anything. If I try to ping it, the server responds "Destination host unreachable.". I know this isn't much information to resolve this problem but I really don't know where to start looking for. Which log file might be recording failures what causes this kind of problem. This might be a HW issue or maybe temperatures cause my server did this same thing before I reinstalled ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

1. you might login locally and check if server got networking working properly
2. you might check /var/log/syslog ( general messages about whats going on on a server )
3. you check logs of applications running on a server ( maybe one of those crash and causes some damages )

Comment: This found on syslog.


Jun 13 07:10:00 Viped-server smbd[1248]:   failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
Jun 13 07:17:01 Viped-server CRON[17244]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 13 07:23:00 Viped-server smbd[17508]: [2014/06/13 07:23:00.626663,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
Jun 13 07:23:00 Viped-server smbd[17508]:   Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Bad file descriptor
Jun 13 07:23:00 Viped-server smbd[1248]: [2014/06/13 07:23:00.627053,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)

Comment: Sudo crontab -e is empty and on my own crontab there is only line that handles my domain update. And on my samba settings there is nothing about printers. I really don't know where to continue looking for this error. That line was like million times on syslog so thats probably the source of problem.